# Share Models Between Two Different Django Projects

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have two different Django projects which should be using exactly the same db & same models and working on different servers. I don’t want to define same models twice in both apps since the models might change and changes should be done on both sides. What would be the best solution to define models once and use the same models in both projects?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar approach to access a legacy database from some others django projects. I built a normal django project with the common models and methods. Next, in the others projects, at the top of my `settings_local.py` file, I added this common project to the python path:

```py
import os
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'my', 'relative', 'path', 'to', 'common_project'))
```

And then add the apps in the common project to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the dependant others.

So, I was able to import theese common models easy:

```py
from common_project.app.models import MyModel
```

Comment: The thing is, the projects are gonna work on different servers. So I am not able to add the path to the python path.

Comment: @TalhaEryasar, you need to upload the common project on these servers. The idea is to keep the common code in a separate and controllable source, not duplicated in all projects, and easy to maintain in the future.